# Attempting to modify typesafe activator UI. How do I import/modify the activator jar files in eclipse scala IDE?

Tags: eclipse, scala, jar, typesafe-activator, typesafe

I am new to the scala eclipse environment and also new to typesafe/activator.

I need to modify some of the activator initialization code because of some very specific host-side dependencies.

I cannot see how to "import" the actual jar files into eclipse. I know exactly what I need to change and how (via manually opening the jar and looking at the code). But I want to maintain complete integrity with the change management (ivy and sbt) but I do understand how to do this.

Is there some basic way to pull in/open a source jar, modify it, and build/deploy it? I see lots of help on the export/build, but I need help with the open/import/modify portion of this task.

Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you wanted to change how a project works you'd go back to the source repository (in Activator's case https://github.com/typesafehub/activator ) and modify from there and then rebuild. Source jars don't have the build configuration so they are not useful for creating new binaries. Usually source jars are used to show source in a debugger or to click on a type in the IDE and see the source code for that type.

Comment: Thanks.  I sorta figured that since nobody answered for a while. It seems a bit cumbersome in the case of a huge project like this, but it will need to be done for a very few things I need to do. So I guess it will require a fork when I need to.   I'mma classic newbie to this. :-)